# While installing Hadoop in ubuntu for the command '$sudo gedit ~/.bashrc' I'm getting unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

Tags: sudo, gedit, bashrc

Here is picture of my command and it's error
[image: Here is picture of my command and it's error]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running on a text terminal. `gedit` needs a GUI terminal.

Use a different editor, `nano`, `vi`, `vim`, `ed`, ...